# Do birth marks signify anything?

Tags: karma, symbolism, human, birth

I understand that it may sound little absurd but I have noticed that some people have birth marks and some have none, some birth marks are pretty prominent ones.

**My question**: Do birth marks tell something about the previous birth or reveal any other facts? Are there any references to them anywhere? Are they in any way related to the ***karmas*** of previous birth?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Do birth marks tell something about the previous birth or reveal any other facts?

**Yes they do** [**Garuda Purana**](http://archive.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/garud-puran/garuda-vol-2/chapter-01/topic-29) - Vol. one - Achar Kanda - Chapter -64,65 are about **Samudrika science** which gives us detail description of Birthmarks both  on males as well as females.

- Chapter 64 - समुद्रिकानुसारेण स्त्री-नर लक्ष णम् ( A brief discourse on the auspicious or inauspicious marks on the person of females.
- Chapter 65  विस्तरत: समुद्रिकानुसारेण स्त्री-नर लक्ष णम्  ( auspicious marks on men and women as disclosed by science of Samudrikam.

According to Garuda purana these birth marks are either auspicious or inauspicious. And they do tell us about the personality, the situations a person going to face in the future, financial condition, death (in own or foreign country), about obtaining wealth, about getting good husband or wife, future of sons/daughters, eating habits, royalty, intellect, behavior, personality traits etc.

So these marks are good indicators of a mans of woman's current life.

---

Here are some of the shlokas from Garuda Purana -:

> शङ्खातपत्रशिविकागजपद्मोपमा नृपे ॥
>  कुम्भाङ्कुशपताकाभा मृणालाभा
>   निधीश्वरे ॥ 65.49 ॥
>
> The signs of conch-shell ,umbrella , vehicle ,elephant and lotus
>   indicate royalty. The marks of pitcher ,goad ,flag and lotus-stalk 
>   indicate the possession of gems.
>
> ---
>
> या च काञ्चनवर्णाभा
>   रक्तहस्तसरोरुहा ॥
>  सहस्त्राणां तु नारीणां भवेत्सापि पतिव्रता ॥ 64.2
>   ॥
>
> A women whose color is like that of gold ,and and whose hands are red
>   ,is called Padmini .Such a women ,born in a thousand is
>   personification of chastity.
>
> ---
>
> निः स्वाश्च कुनखैस्तद्वद्विवर्णैः
>   परतर्ककाः ॥
>  ताम्रैर्भूपा धनाढ्याश्च अङ्गुष्ठैः सयवैस्तथा ॥ 65.45
>   ॥
>
> Those who have discolored and disfigured nails ,always pry into
>   others business .Those who have  copper colored  nails, become kings
>   the mark of a barley on their thumbs,become rich.
>
> अङ्गुष्ठमूलजैः पुत्री स्याद्दीर्घांगुलिपर्वकः ॥
>  दीर्घायुः
>   सुभगश्चैव निर्धनो विरलाङ्गुलिः ॥ 65.46 ॥
>
> When there is such a mark at the foot of the thumb a person gets sons.
>   If a person has long knots in the fingers he lives a long life and
>   becomes lucky . He who has dis-joined fingers become poor.
>
> ---
>
> यस्याः पाणितले रेखा प्राकारस्तोरणं भवेत् ॥
>  अपि दासकुले जाता
>   राज्ञीत्वमुपगच्छति ॥ 64.9 ॥
>
> The women who ,has the marks of a wall or gateway on her palms becomes
>   a queen even if she is born as a maid servant.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it has significance in the Samudra Shastra part of astrology. Which tries to predict the nature and future of a native by studying his/her various bodily signs, palm lines etc.

We can find some details of the effects of birth marks, moles etc on the future of a native [in this chapter of Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra](http://www.astrojyoti.com/bphspage9-9.htm):

> **Ch. 82. Effects of Moles, Marks, Signs etc. for Men and Women**
>
> 1. Mahārśi Parasara said. O Maitreya! Now I will describe to you the effects of moles, marks, spots and signs, found on the body of women
>      and men.
>
> 2-3. A mole, spot, or figure, formed by hair on the left side of a
>   woman and right side of a man is auspicious. If there is mole on the
>   chest of a woman, she will be fortunate. A woman, who has a red mark,
>   like a mole etc., on her right breast, begets many children and she is
>   blessed with all kinds of enjoyments and comforts.
>
> 4. The woman, who has a red mark (mole) on her left breast, begets only one son.
> 5. The woman, who has a mole on her right breast, begets many daughters and sons.
> 6. There will be gain, or acquisition of a kingdom, if there, as is a red mole etc on the forehead, or in the middle of (between) the eyebrows. The
>      person will enjoy sweetish preparations, if there is such a mark on
>      the cheeks.
>
> 7-10. The woman, who has a red mark (mole etc.) on her nose, becomes
>   consort of a king. If the mark be blackish, the woman concerned
>   becomes an adulteress, or widow. All the marks below the navel are
>   auspicious for both men and women. If there be moles etc. on the ears,
>   cheeks, or neck of a man, his first issue will be male and he will
>   enjoy good fortune and happiness. The man, who has moles etc. in the
>   thighs, suffers misery.
>
> 11. The woman, who has the sign of trident on her forehead, becomes a queen. Such a mark on the forehead of a man makes him a king.

Also, [the Horasara](http://www.astrojyoti.com/horasarapage2-2.htm) (which was composed by Varahmihira's son) gives some information about what combinations in the horoscope lead to moles or marks on which parts of the body etc.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation, also wanted to know are they in any way related to the karmas of previous birth?

Comment: @Just_Do_It Yes they must be related because what we had done in previous lives is what we are getting now..but Parashara Hora Shastra does not mention anything about that..