# What does Hinduism say about having multiple birthmarks on a body?

Tags: belief, body

I have seen or heard people talk about their birthmarks and noticed that they only have one..but not in my case; I have a total of six birthmarks on my body...one of the birthmarks is on my back and it looks like a bat. Does this have any significance?

Comment: probably similar question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23763/11875